# Can I counter the English opening with the same setup as the Pirc defense?

Tags: opening, english-opening

How can I counter hypermodern openings such as English opening when I play as black?

Comment: Since c4 is, just from "classical aspect", unaggressive, you can play almost anything. Including Pirc ;-) (Just a few days ago, someone played this against me: 1.c4 e5 2.Nc3 Nf6 3.g3 d5 4.cxd5 Nxd5 5.Bg2 Nxc3 6.bxc3, i.e. an atrocious reverse Sicilian Dragon for Black. It was perfectly playable.) Take a look into the LiChess Master database - even 1...g5 has only +9% for White, although n is far too small for this stats to be meaningful. (If you totally trust LiChess stats, play 1...b6, +1%.)

Comment: Do you mean 1 ... d6 ? 1 e4 d6 is the Pirc Defence  -- nothing else is.

Comment: You'll end up in a Kings Indian line or a Modern.  The distinguishing feature of the Pirc rather than the Modern is that white's c-pawn is blocked by by the knight on c3, so this won't be a Pirc.

Comment: @RosieF So 1.e4 d6 2.Nf3 e5 is a Pirc defence but 1.d4 d6 2.e4 Nf6 is not?

Comment: @bof Yes, games starting with different openings can reach the same position. But we use opening-labels to label move-sequences (1 d4 Nf6 2 c4 e6 3 Nf3 d5 is a QID, but 1 d4 d5 2 c4 e6 3 Nf3 Nf6 is a QGD) rather than sets of positions, don't we?  If we had to do the latter, labelling would be too complicated. Anyway, my point was not to engage in that debate, but rather to challenge the implication that 1 ... d6 as such (rather than specifically 1 e4 d6) is the Pirc. I see that the OP has improved the question's wording anyway.

Comment: I think the real issue here is that the OP needs to clarify what they want. As a Pirc player I would say you can't get into a Pirc type setup against the English as the pawn on c4 fundamentally changes the position - you are now in Kings Indian territory, which while related also has a lot of differences. What I think is really being asked is "Can I play a ... d6 ... g6 ... Bg7" type set up against the English - to which the answer is yes, but before that answer can be given the OP needs to clarify that that is what they want.